# how to format a string value to double decimal format

Tags: java

```
Number Format nf = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.US); 
DecimalFormat df = (DecimalFormat)nf;
df.applyPattern("$###,###.###");
String format_val=df.format(4596.37);
num = new jxl.write.Number(i, j,Double.parseDouble(format_val),arial10format);
```

here I'm getting `NumberFormatException` :

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "$4,596.37"
```

how to  solve this one?

Comment: `$4,928.25` is not a valid format for `Double.parseDouble`.  In this case I question why you're formatting the value of `4596.37` at all and not just writing it to the `jxl.write.Number`

Comment: 4596.37 is a double value, i want to represent that value with $ symbol separated by commas...@MadProgrammer

Comment: @RvN But then it's not a valid Number!

Comment: First `4596.37` isn't a `String` value, it's a `double`, second, if you want to use the format, why then do you use `Double.parseDouble(format_val)` to try and parse (`$4,928.25`) it back to a `double`?  A number has no concept of format

Comment: You should be letting the cell take care of the formatting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I "think" you want (I've not tried this) is to let the cell take care of the formatting, for example...

```
NumberFormat decimalNo = new NumberFormat("$###,###.###"); 
WritableCellFormat numberFormat = new WritableCellFormat(decimalNo);
//write to datasheet
Number numberCell = new Number(i, j, 4596.37, numberFormat); 
excelSheet.addCell(numberCell);
```

Take a look at [`WritableCellFormat`](http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/resources/javadocs/2_6_10/docs/jxl/write/WritableCellFormat.html) for more details

What you've tried to do is...

1. Convert the `double` value `4596.37` to a `String`, with the format of `$###,###.###`
2. Try and convert `$4,596.37` back to a `double`...which fails as the `String` you've passed to does not conform to the requirements of a `double`...

A number has no concept of format, that's what formatters are for.  In this case, however, the Excel cell has it's own internal formatting capabilities which can take care of this for you

Answer (score 0):

you can use the same DecimalFormat instance you used to create the string to parse it too by using the `parse()` method

see the javaDoc for more details

[http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html#parse(java.lang.String,%20java.text.ParsePosition)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html#parse%28java.lang.String,%20java.text.ParsePosition%29)